# Checking a variable meanwhile calling the functions needed

Tags: c

So im fairly new to programming and I ran into something which I cannot figure out.

I'll demonstrate my problem.

```
int main(void){

    int number;

    if(number == 1){
        number1();
    }else if(number == 2){
        number2();
    }else if(number == 3){
        number3();
    }else if(number == 4){
        number4();
    }else if(number == 5){
        number5();
    }else if(number == 6){
        number6();
    }else if(number == 7){
        number7();
    }else if(number == 8){
        number8();
    }else if(number == 9){
        number9();
    }else if(number == 0){
        number0();
    } else if (number >= 10 && <= 19){
        number1();
        number2(25);
    }

}

void number1(int Q){
    VGA_box(X + 5 + Q, 20, X+7 + Q, 60, white);
}

void number2(int Q){
    VGA_box(X + Q, 20, X+ 20 + Q, 22, white);           
    VGA_box(X + 18 + Q, 22, X+ 20 + Q, 38, white);      
    VGA_box(X + Q, 38, X+ 20 + Q, 40, white);           
    VGA_box(X + Q, 40, X+ 2 + Q, 58, white);            
    VGA_box(X + Q, 58, X+ 20 + Q, 60, white);                   
}
```

Please ignore the functions `VGA_box()`, since this is just a function to write a line/box.

I'm making a little game and I would like to add a scoreboard, but here is my problem:

Since I'm drawing the numbers (so they look better IMO), I have to call functions, functions which represent a number. So if number = 1, function `number1();` is called.
Is there an easy way to call the functions `number2()`, `number5()` and `number9()` if the number is 259? Or lets say; 632. The only possible way I can figure out is to use a lot of if-statements but that will take me a while to do.

Is it possible to use a for-loop which keeps track of what the number is and calls the functions which needed?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `switch-case` and function pointers, but that's too broad already...

Comment: put function pointers inside an array,and use the numbers as indices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an array of pointers to function and a recursive function to reverse the value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void func0(void) { printf("0\n"); }
static void func1(void) { printf("1\n"); }
static void func2(void) { printf("2\n"); }
static void func3(void) { printf("3\n"); }

static void (*func[])(void) = {func0, func1, func2, func3};

static void exec(int value)
{
    if (value) {
        exec(value / 10);
        func[value % 10]();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    exec(123);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

As pointed out by @user3078414 in comments this fails when `exec(012)` is passed (the first `0` is not evaluated in the recursive function), in addition, `012` is interpreted as an octal (not as a decimal).

An alternative using strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void func0(void) { printf("0\n"); }
static void func1(void) { printf("1\n"); }
static void func2(void) { printf("2\n"); }
static void func3(void) { printf("3\n"); }

static void (*func[])(void) = {func0, func1, func2, func3};

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr = "012";

    while (*ptr) {
        func[*ptr - '0']();
        ptr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's beautiful. Should likely be updated with func[4,9] for the OP case.

Comment: @Nightcrawler Thank you :) is only an idea, OP can adapt this to his requirements

Comment: Looks great, but I have a little question with `func0()` in your code, @Alter Mann. If a number starts with zero or is zero, `func0()` is never reached. So, zero is treated as a only number if it has meaning within common decimal system.  Please, try `exec(012)` or `exec(0)`. Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: @user3078414: a number can be written down in different bases, e.g. decimal, binary, octal, hex. When you write `012`, it is interpreted as an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number, which equals a decimal `10`. You might be better off working with *numeric strings*, such as `"012"` (that will require changes to the given code).

Comment: @user3078414 In this case, as pointed out by Dcoder, use a string: https://ideone.com/FUgOzO

Comment: Thanks, your comment great addendum to your code, @Alter Mann.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me very much.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create function `drawDigit(int digit)` where `digit` is a single digit number between 0 and 9.
   You *can* use function pointers to select which `number` function to call, but if that is too complex, you can use the `if`/`else` method for now.
2. Convert score to string:

   ```
   int score = 259;
   char digits[SIZE];  // Size must be large enough to hold all digits and nul character ('\0')
   int numDigits = snprintf(digits, SIZE, "%d", score);  // snprintf is from "stdio.h"
   // digits contains now 4 character string "259" with nul character at the end
   ```
3. Loop over string to draw all digits:

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i) {
       int digit = digits[i] - '0';  // Convert character digit to numeric digit
       drawDigit(digit);
   }
   ```

You probably need extra a parameter to `drawDigit` function to adjust the horizontal placement, but I'll leave that exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like functions number1(), number2(), etc are quite similar. I'd be against creating different functions; I'd rather create one single function (let's say number()) which receives the whole number "632" from your example, and loops digit by digit.

Creating one single function is easier to handle by you. Just check that the resulting function is not too big, but it's quite likely that functions number1(), number2(), etc have a lot of code in common. If that's the case, reducing redundancy and repetition in code is highly recommended!

Let me know if I'm right with this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointer to function, e.g:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*typ_callback)(int);

static void number1(int Q);
static void number2(int Q);

typ_callback my_table[] = { NULL, number1, number2 };

int main(void)
{
    size_t number;

    printf("Entern the number of callback: ");
    scanf("%zu", &number);

    if (number <= (sizeof(my_table)/sizeof(my_table[0])))
    {
        if (my_table[number] != NULL)
        {
            my_table[number](number);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Wrong number\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

static void number1(int Q)
{
    printf("You called %s function with passing value %d\n", __func__, Q);
}

static void number2(int Q)
{
    printf("You called %s function with passing value %d\n", __func__, Q);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

***Function pointers and switch/case are not the solution !***

The problem is not *if-statement* or even the functions. Since your algorithms to draw scores are very different in each function then you can not stop using lots of conditions, so you have to some where call them by lots of `if` statements.

The solution is to find an uniform algorithm to draw scores on the screen for every number. For example write 10 functions to draw digits between [0..9], then use this functions to draw numbers with arbitrary length numbers.